# Component will preserve state after unmounting it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Component will preserve state even after unmounting it

I'm building a feedback form with Formik and want to move from class components to hooks but face mentioned difficulties.

```
function Feedback(props) {
  const [fileInfo, setFileInfo] = useState("");
  const [feedbackStatus, setFeedbackStatus] = useState("");
  let timer = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    const status = props.feedbackResponse.status;

    if (status) {

      if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
        setFeedbackStatus("success");
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
          props.history.goBack();
        }, 2500);
      } else if (status === "pending") {
        setFeedbackStatus("pending");
      } else {
        setFeedbackStatus("error");
      }

    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, [props.feedbackResponse.status]);

  // ...code ommited for brevity
}
```

This effect runs succesfully after my form submission while waiting for a server response. `Feedback` component is a `react-router` modal component, if it matters. However, if I re-open that modal, I see a success message instead of a new form. In my `return` I am conditionally rendering a success message if `feedbackStatus === "success"` or a form that, depending on a server response, might display an error message otherwise. My class component works fine with this code:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     const status = this.props.feedbackResponse.status;
     if (prevProps.feedbackResponse.status !== status) {
       if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
         this.setState({feedbackStatus: "success"});
         this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
           this.props.history.goBack();
         }, 2500);
       } else if (status === "pending") {
         this.setState({feedbackStatus: "pending"});
       } else {
         this.setState({feedbackStatus: "error"});
       };
     }
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
     clearInterval(this.timer);
   }
```

Expected output: reopening this modal component after a successful form submit should render a new form but it renders a previous' submit status. This leads me to think that I'm not unmounting my `Feedback` component at all but where's my mistake then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above behaviour happens because the effect is run on initial render as well and in that case `props.feedbackStatus` might be preserved from the previous instances.

Since you only wish to execute the effect when the component updates, you would need to **stop execution of useEffect on initial render** which happens even when you pass values to the dependency array. You can do that using `useRef`

```
function Feedback(props) {
  const [fileInfo, setFileInfo] = useState("");
  const [feedbackStatus, setFeedbackStatus] = useState("");
  const isInitialRender = useRef(true);
  let timer = null;


  useEffect(() => {
    if(isInitialRender.current === true) {
        isInitialRender.current = false;
    } else {
        const status = props.feedbackResponse.status;

        if (status) {

          if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
            setFeedbackStatus("success");
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
              props.history.goBack();
            }, 2500);
          } else if (status === "pending") {
            setFeedbackStatus("pending");
          } else {
            setFeedbackStatus("error");
          }

        }
   }
        return () => {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, [props.feedbackResponse.status]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<Feedback key={someKey} />`.

This will ensure that a new instance of Feedback component is made when you re-open it, thus your old success/failure messages will be erased from the state.